# C# WebSocket - WebSocketException while receiving data

Tags: c#, exception, websocket

I wrote a program for the fire department to receive data from the control center.
When receiving status data, it works perfectly. But now when we would have received the first alarm via this WebSocket interface, the following error occurred:

```
System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException (0x80004005): The remote party closed the WebSocket connection without completing the close handshake.
   at System.Net.WebSockets.ManagedWebSocket.ThrowIfEOFUnexpected(Boolean throwOnPrematureClosure)                  
   at System.Net.WebSockets.ManagedWebSocket.EnsureBufferContainsAsync(Int32 minimumRequiredBytes, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean throwOnPrematureClosure)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.ManagedWebSocket.ReceiveAsyncPrivate[TWebSocketReceiveResultGetter,TWebSocketReceiveResult](Memory`1 payloadBuffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken, TWebSocketReceiveResultGetter resultGetter)
   at FF.Service.Services.XYZService.GetDataAsync(Boolean isRetrying) in C:\Users\XXX\source\repos\FF.Service\FF.Service\Services\XYZService.cs:line 108
```

But I don't find the error in my code:

```
using (ClientWebSocket socket = new ClientWebSocket())
{
     // set login tokens as request headers
    socket.Options.SetRequestHeader("master_token", masterToken);
    socket.Options.SetRequestHeader("sub_token", subToken);

    // read certificate string from file and prepare for certificate creation
    string certificateContent = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Program.AssemblyDirectory, "ff-cloud.pem"))
                                        .Trim()
                                        .Replace("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----", null)
                                        .Replace("-----END CERTIFICATE-----", null);

    // create certificate and add to web socket options
    X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(certificateContent));
    socket.Options.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);

    // ignore certificate errors
    socket.Options.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

    // set buffer and buffer size
    int bufferSize = 8192;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    // connect the web socket to the remote server
    await socket.ConnectAsync(new Uri(fullServerAddress), CancellationToken.None);

    // work while connection is open
    while (socket.State == System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketState.Open)
    {
        State = WebSocketState.Open;
        WebSocketReceiveResult receiveResult;
        MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream(bufferSize);

        do
        {
            // receive data
            // IN THE NEXT LINE OCCURS THE ERROR!!!!
            receiveResult = await socket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);

            if (receiveResult.MessageType != WebSocketMessageType.Close)
                            outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, receiveResult.Count);
            }
                // read while end of message isn't reached
                while (!receiveResult.EndOfMessage);

                // set the output stream position to 0 - to read from the beginning
                outputStream.Position = 0;

                // read the message
                StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(outputStream);
                string message = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

                LogService.GetInstance().Log(message, LogService.LogTypes.AllData);
                // check if the message is alarm data
                if (message.Contains("alarm_data"))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // deserialize received data to alarm data
                        FF.AlarmData.Rootobject rootobject =
                                JsonSerializer.Deserialize<FF.AlarmData.Rootobject>(message);

                        LogService.GetInstance().Log("Successfully received alarm data!", LogService.LogTypes.Success);

                        // fire the alarm received event
                        if (AlarmReceived != null)
                            AlarmReceived(this, new AlarmEventArgs(rootobject));
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        LogService.GetInstance().Log($"Error at receiveing alarm data! ({ex.Message})", LogService.LogTypes.Error);
                    }
                }
                // check if the message is a radio status
                else if (message.Contains("radio_status"))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // deserialize received data to radio status
                        FF.StatusData.Rootobject rootobject =
                            JsonSerializer.Deserialize<FF.StatusData.Rootobject>(message);

                        LogService.GetInstance().Log("Successfully received status data!", LogService.LogTypes.Success);

                        // fire the status received event
                        if (StatusReceived != null)
                            StatusReceived(this, new StatusEventArgs(rootobject));

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        LogService.GetInstance().Log($"Error at receiveing status data! ({ex.Message})", LogService.LogTypes.Error);
                    }
                }
                // break the loop if the received message is a close message
                if (receiveResult.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
                    break;
            }

            LogService.GetInstance().Log("Connection lost!", LogService.LogTypes.Warning);

            try
            {
                LogService.GetInstance().Log("Try to close connection!", LogService.LogTypes.Information);

                // close web socket connection
                await socket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, null, CancellationToken.None);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogService.GetInstance().Log($"Error on closing connection: {ex.ToString()}", LogService.LogTypes.Warning);
            }
        }
```

The error occurs int the line unter the comment "IN THE NEXT LINE OCCURS THE ERROR!!!!". Unfortunatelly there is no way to receive alarm data only for testing.

Does someone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you in forward for your answers

Regards Matthias

Comment: Why do you have a DO Loop?  Does the code fail first time trough loop of second time?  it is best to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to help find issue.  You are using HTTPS (secure) which uses TLS for authentication.  You must be using TLS 1.2 or 1.3 (other versions are obsolete).  When using HTTPS the TLS is done before the HTTP Request.  The server send out a certificate block that contains the names of the certificate that can be used for authentication.  The client certificate has to be one of the names that is sent from the server.  So with sniffer check version of TLS.

Comment: Also check if the name of the certificate you are using matches one of the names in the certificate block.  to make sure you are using Net 4.7.2 ort later and that the config file is using Operating System for TLS.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. But I don't think, that it fails because of the certificate, because I already has a connection. From the server I can get two kinds of messages. One kind is the status of our fire truck and the outher kind of message is a alarm message. The status message is working without problems. Only when I receive a alarm message I get the error. And the error occurs at the ReceiveAsync method.

Comment: You are getting an exception because the connection closed.  We do not know much more than that.  Then best way of isolating issue is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  The TLS authentication is performed before the request is sent.  So if you are seeing a REQUEST than TLS passed.  You can also compare the working and non working request.  Check if the version of TLS is same.  Also check if the request are using HTTP or HTTPS.